# Why is my block declaration giving me an incompatible pointer error?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks

I'm declaring a block like this:

```
void (^callback)(NSString *_accessToken) = ^{
  // do something interesting with _accessToken
}
```

but XCode keeps telling me

```
Incompatible block pointer types initializing void(^__strong)(NSString *__strong)
with an expression of type void (^)(void)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void (^callback)(NSString *) = ^(NSString *_accessToken){
  // do something interesting with _accessToken
}
```